# Need help understanding Javascript setinterval and function declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to js and jquery  and need help understanding why this script does not work. I've checked it over any number of times, but in all my research, there is something that I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.  The code should just set text value in div once every 2 seconds. I cut this code down from its real functionality so ignore the fact that it does nothing.  Forgive and correct me if I am not posting this properly. It's my first post.
code below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var test=0;
      var timer = setInterval(save_it(), 2000);
      var test=0;
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var save_it = function(){
            testdiv.innerhtml = test++;
          };
        });
     </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="testdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should never see `functionname()` inside a `setInterval`. There are cases where it's possible, but only if `functionname` itself returns a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example (jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Br59d/)

HTML:

```
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var test=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer = setInterval(save_it, 2000);
});

function save_it(){
    $('#testdiv').html(test.toString());
    test++;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide some input:

```
var save_it = function() {
```

and

```
function save_it() {
```

act two separate ways. If you use var save_it = function() you can't call that function before the declaration.

i.e. you couldn't do this:

```
save_it();
var save_it = function() {
    alert('k');
}
```

however, if you use function save_it() you can.

```
save_it();
function save_it() {
    alert('k');
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/nmSD6/